# Jekyll or Hugo theme with multilanguage support

Tags: internationalization, jekyll, github-pages, multilingual, hugo

I'd like to start designing a website using Jekyll or Hugo. The plan is to publish it on GitHub or GitLab pages.

After hours of searching I'm pretty confused about all the facts. Hugo support natively a [multilanguage utility](https://gohugo.io/tutorials/create-a-multilingual-site/) while Jekyll not. There are some plugins for Jekyll but plugins are not supported on GitHub pages anyway.

With Jekyll I tried to follow [this solution](https://www.sylvaindurand.org/making-jekyll-multilingual/) without any concrete solution for the translation of the layouts while with Hugo I've found the instruction pretty confused (but that's my fault).

What I'm looking for is a theme (Jekyll or Hugo it doesn't matter) that is already designed with 2 (or more) languages.

Answer (score 4):

Beside the [official Hugo instructions for creating a multilingual site](https://gohugo.io/tutorials/create-a-multilingual-site/), you also have:

- [multilingual examples](https://github.com/spf13/hugo/tree/master/examples/multilingual) which has been [recently updated](https://github.com/spf13/hugo/commit/68ebf61613ca5715969818e60343920b4e751933)
- [multilingual mode](https://gohugo.io/content/multilingual/)
- themes with multilingual already baked in as (from the [Hugo themes list site](http://themes.gohugo.io/)):

  - [hugo-scriptor-theme](https://github.com/bep/hugo-multilingual/tree/master/themes/hugo-scriptor-theme)
  - [dimension](https://github.com/sethmacleod/dimension)
  - [docuapi](http://themes.gohugo.io/docuapi/)

Plus, with Hugo 0.87 (Aug. 2021), you also have [Date/time formatting layouts and localized string for the current language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68642957/6309).

Comment: thanks for the information and sorry for the delay. I will have a look at the documentation you sent.. the difficulties I'm having with both Jekyll and Hugo (but I'm totally not an expert) is to find a straightforward way to translate both layouts and post/pages. Putting all what has to be translated in the `yaml` files is quite not so immediate..

Comment: I agree, and I have created this issue in Hugo to track it: https://github.com/spf13/hugo/issues/3360

Comment: Hi, hugo-scriptor-theme and dimension are dead links now.

Answer (score 2):

As well as the themes that VonC linked to, there is the [Beautiful Hugo theme](https://github.com/halogenica/beautifulhugo) which I recently updated to work with multilingual sites.

I also recently made an example of a multilingual Hugo site in [hugo-multilingual-example](https://github.com/rayjolt/hugo-multilingual-example) at Github, so you can compare that with the example in the Hugo repository that VonC linked to.

With Hugo, you should ignore the "Create a Multilingual Site" tutorial, as it was made before the native multilingual support was added, and is now outdated. Instead, you should base everything on the "multilingual mode" documentation.

Hopefully that should be enough to get you started, but let us know if you have any other problems.

Answer (score 1):

I localized a Jekyll theme to output to German and Japanese [here](https://github.com/amzn/appstore-alexa-docs/). It depends what requirements you're trying to support. We sent out translated files to a translation agency and then reimported them back into the project.

My strategy in defining the theme was to put each language in its own collection. Each collection defines default values for top nav and footer to be in that language.

Additionally, I used a different config file for each language. The language's config file defined strings for that language. File names and URLs remained in English.

Comment: I've been planning to write a localization tutorial for Jekyll at some point. It would be good to know what requirements you have for your project, if you want to share any details.

Comment: Hi Tom.. a straightforward tutorial would be really nice and appreciated! Well in a few words I think that: 1. nice and easy way to have buttons(or dropdowns) to switch languages 2. url(s) for each language (it/mysite.com vs en/mysite.com etc..) 3. easy way to translate contents (awesome would be to have some po file and automatic generation of output with language detected)... Much much more ;) I can help in some way if you want!