# How to render correct datetime in hugo post?

Tags: blogs, hugo, toml

I created a post using hugo `new posts/mypost.md` and it created mypost.md for me with header toml configuration like that

[image: toml config]

But, when i run on server (local), the datetime rendered wrong like:
[image]

How can I fix that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

This is how I got it to work:

Add your date format in `config.toml`

```
[params]
    dateFormat = "02 Jan 2006"
```

Your post should contain the date in its front-matter:

```
---
date: "2020-12-23T15:21:54+05:30"
...
---
```

Use the format in your layout:

```
<div>{{ .Params.date.Format .Site.Params.dateFormat }}</div>
```

**Note**: Please DO NOT change the numbers in the date format. It must be 02 for day, Jan for month, 2006 for year, etc. check [this](https://gohugohq.com/howto/hugo-dateformat/) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

Check also [Hugo 0.87](https://gohugo.io/news/0.87.0-relnotes/) (Aug. 2021, two years later), which comes with:

- a [`timezone`](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration/#timezone)
- a [timedate format](https://gohugo.io/functions/dateformat/)

  ```
  {{ time.Format "Monday, Jan 2, 2006" "2015-01-21" }} 
  → 
  "Wednesday, Jan 21, 2015"
  ```

> Note that since Hugo 0.87.0, `time.Format` will return a localized string for the current language.

- Date/time formatting layouts

  ```
  {{ .Date | time.Format ":date_long" }}
  ```

The full list of custom layouts with examples for English:

```
:date_full => Wednesday, June 6, 2018

:date_long => June 6, 2018

:date_medium => Jun 6, 2018

:date_short => 6/6/18

:time_full => 2:09:37 am UTC

:time_long => 2:09:37 am UTC

:time_medium => 2:09:37 am

:time_short => 2:09 am
```

Answer (score 3):

In Hugo [v0.95.0](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/tree/v0.95.0) (released 16 Mar 2022),  it should be

```js
[params]
    date_format = "02 Jan 2006"
```

with

```js
---
date: 2022-03-18T21:10:00+07:00
---
```

in the post front matter, where double quote marks are not necessary. I used [Ananke theme](https://github.com/theNewDynamic/gohugo-theme-ananke).

Comment: For me it was `date_format = "02.01.2006"` to have the european format

Answer (score 2):

Setting the date_format in the config file seems weird to me. I would set the following in the config file:

```
defaultContentLanguage: nl
languageCode: nl_NL
```

These are variables that do NOT go into params, but on the root level of the config file. When you have these you can simply call:

```
{{ .Date | time.Format ":date_long" }}
```

or... if you need another format:

```
{{ .Date | time.Format ":date_medium" }}
```

The date will be formatted in your language.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set dateformat in file config.toml at 2.1.2006 (any proper format, ensure 2, Jan, 2006).
[This link save my day](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/date-time-format-in-config-toml/5268)